# Is it possible to add Notification Center to a cpp class in objective-c++

Tags: objective-c

I would like to add notification center from a cpp class, is it possible????

If so, how do I do it?

Manager.h

```
class Manager
{

  Manager();

};
```

Manger.mm file

```
Manager:Manager()
{
[[NSNotificationCenter dafaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(workermethod) name:@" Name" object:(id)nil];
}
```

My compiler gives an error saying self is not declared.......yes i know it is an obvious error.

Since I'm not deriving from NSObject....
Please let me know if it is possible to add notification center to cpp class in Cocoa??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No, you can't do that.**

The Objective-C and C++ class hierarchies are separate. In a C++ context, `self` is not defined but `this` is defined. In an Objective-C context, `this` is not defined and `self` is.

Also, `addObserver` takes an `id` parameter. C++ object instances are not considered of type `id` so even if you change your code to pass `this` instead of `self` it won't compile.

See the [C++ Limitations](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCPlusPlus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH10-SW2) from the Objective-C Programming Language Manual.

As a workaround, create an Objectve-C class which has an instance of the C++ object you want the notification to go to, and simply call the C++ method on it when the Objective-C object gets the notification.

Comment: Then can you suggest me any alternative....Its a big project..I cant change the cpp calling style to objective-c in all the classes.Im opting for notification center bcoz i cannot handle the thread synchronization using events in objetive-c.

Comment: Not only are the class hierarchies separate, but even though C++ and Objective-C both have things called "objects" and "classes", they are completely different things in the two languages. It's like if somebody called started calling telegraphs "cellphones" — you still wouldn't be able to use a telegraph like a cellphone.

Answer (score 0):

As Ben S pointed out, you can't use a C++ object where an Objective-C object is expected. They're just not the same thing. If you're targeting 10.6, one alternative to making an Objective-C wrapper is to use NSNotificationCenter's `addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:`. Just give it a block that calls a function on your object and you get the same effect as adding that object as an observer.

Just to emphasize, though, that is only possible on 10.6.