# CF equivalent of [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]

Tags: objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

I want to use a cpp function as observer callback.
Out of CFNotificationCenterGet**DarwinNotify/Distributed/Local**Center, CFNotificationCenterGetLocalCenter seems closest to [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter].

Is CFNotificationCenterGetLocalCenter equivalent to [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]?

EDIT:I am in doubt because
An answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923878/is-it-possible-to-add-notification-center-to-a-cpp-class-in-objective-c) says - You cannot add observer throuh C++ class
But the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062299/how-to-add-an-observer-to-nsnotificationcenter-in-a-c-class-using-objective-c) says - You can add observer in C++ class through CF functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSNotificationCenter and CFNotificationCenter are **not** toll-free bridged (see: [definitive list of toll-free bridged types](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html)), so if you are trying to receive notifications posted by AppKit on the specific NSNotificationCenter instance returned by `+[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]` it would seem *safest* to use Objective-C, at the very least to interact with that instance of NSNotificationCenter.  Your Objective-C class can be quite thin, and simply call through to your C++ class, but there's no avoiding Objective-C if those are the specific notifications you wish to receive.

EDIT: Empirically, yes, posting a notification to one appears to cause the notification to be received by the other, per the comment you copied and pasted.  That said, I see **no mention whatsoever** of this behavior on either the [CFNotificationCenter reference page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFOundation/Reference/CFNotificationCenterRef/Reference/reference.html) nor the [NSNotificationCenter reference page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html), nor does it appear to mentioned in the [Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/) so to rely on such an un-documented implementation detail seems risky.

Comment: The answer in 2nd linked question has a comment: "No, CFNotificationCenter is not toll-free bridged with NSNotificationCenter. So a custom instance of either will not be usable in the other API. However, if you use a standard center in either (e.g. CFNotificationCenterGetLocalCenter() or [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]) and post a notification to it, the notification is posted to both sets of listeners (i.e. the interfaces are distinct, but the underlying system is the same.)" This makes me believe I can listen to default center notification in    cpp

Comment: And yes there is always an option to have mediator or glue classes but why go with it if system provides some other means? I just want to receive notification by name

Comment: Edited with caveat. Honestly, if you're trying to receive AppKit notifications, not working in the AppKit idiom (i.e. Objective-C) seems like it's making unnecessary work for yourself, but I get that some people have strong feelings about programming languages.

Comment: Undocumented implementation detail - That's exactly what I thought about it and hence posted the question so that if someone who knows that its a defined behavior, can post a link.

Comment: I'm pretty confident that if this were public, documented behavior, that some mention of it would appear in one of the pages I linked to, but I also don't claim exhaustive up-to-date knowledge of all Apple documentation. Either way you go will probably be fine. On the one hand, a ~10 line glue class seems like a small price to pay, but on the other hand, I can't imagine this is behavior that changes very often. Another thought might be to track down a system running 10.5 and see if the behavior is the same there. If it hasn't changed since 10.5, it seems unlikely to change any time soon.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to use a C++ callback for a notification might be to use `-[NSNotificationCenter addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:]` with a small glue block to your C++ code.

Comment: That really seems the best way. Do I need to retain the observer returned by addObserverForName and release after removing observer? I am adding observer in C++ class ctor and removing observer in dtor.

Comment: You don't need to retain it (headers say "The return value is retained by the system"), but you do need to keep a (unretained) reference to it in your C++ object so that you can pass it back to `removeObserver:` in your dtor.